# Torify/torsocks ssh only working from device itself, and not from other devices

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tor, torsocks

While setting up ssh over tor I determined that the ssh only works from the device I try to access (`deviceA`), but not from another device (`deviceB`).

I get a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, verify it is connected through wifi to the internet, completed the sudo apt update and upgrade commands successfully, rebooted successfully, and ran: `sudo apt install tor`. Next, I ran

```
sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc
```

and included:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 22
```

(so not `HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22`)

Next, I restarted the tor service using:

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

This was followed by getting the onion domain of the ssh server with:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/hostname
```

which returned `someoniondomain.onion`.

The next step was to ssh into `deviceA` from `deviceB`, so I copied, using a usb drive to prevent manual typos, the onion address for the ssh service to `deviceB`. On this `deviceB` I ran:

```
sudo apt install tor
sudo apt install torify
torify ssh ubuntu@someoniondomain.onion
```

Where `ubuntu` is the username of `deviceA`. This `torify` command returned:

> 333333333 PERROR torsocks[28775]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
> ssh: connect to host someoniondomaion.onion port 22: Connection refused

So I also ran `sudo systemctl restart tor` on `deviceB` in case that was not set up by torify, yet with the same output.

However, when I run the same command from `deviceA` itself, it successfully ssh's into itself as is indicated by output:

> The authenthicity of host 'someoniondomain.onion (127.42.42.0)' can't be established.
>
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

### Notes

I did not change the `/etc/tor/torrsocks.conf` file, meaning it contains:

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050

OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0
```

My current guess is that the issue might be related to the `OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0` line as `deviceA` and `deviceB` are on the same network, which might somehow cause an issue.

### Question

How can I ensure I am also able to ssh into `deviceA` over tor from `deviceB`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essence of the issue was the assumption that torify sets up a tor connection, which it did not by itself. Furthermore, running:

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

is insufficient on `deviceB` to be able to ssh via tor. It appears one also has to start tor explicitly, as after running the following command on `deviceB`, it worked:

```
sudo tor
```

It is essential to verify the output of the command in [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/how-to-check-if-tor-is-working-and-debug-the-problem-on-cli):

```
curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
```

is `Congratulations` on both devices, to verify they are both connected to tor.